# Not showing the series through loop

Tags: php, html

i am making a program that will first get 2 numbers from user (1.for power ! 1.for factorial)
there are three loops in my program ! 2 loops are used for getting power of first number and shows it in $result . 3rd loop is used for getting factorial of the second number and print it in $result1
now i want to divide the results of power numbers and factorials !
but want to show it in series till the loop end like for "4" ans will be

1
2
4.5
10.66
But i think there is some problem in my code. cant figure out what ! i am stuck

```
<?php 
    $a=$_GET["number"];
    $b=$_GET["number1"];
    for ($i=1;$i<=$a;$i++)
    {
        $result=1;
        for ($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
        {
            $result=$result*$i;
            //echo "$result"."<br/>\n";
        }
        $b=$_GET["number1"];
        $result1=1;
        for ($x=$a; $x>=1; --$x)
        {
            $result1 = $result1*$x;
            echo $result/$result1."</br>";
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is that "`" on line 3 good for?

Comment: What is the actual problem? You've given us what it should be, right? But what is it actually printing?

Comment: The problem is it just print the factorial for one time but i want to show and divide series with series

Comment: Can you explain via an example, what actually do you want?

Comment: i want a program to calculate the series 
result=1+2power2/2!+3power3/3!+4power4/4! ~till the loop end

where power is like 2*2 and ! is factorial like 1+2=3

Comment: You never used $b, what is its significance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

number1 is not used, the only user-input is the number of items in the series.  I changed your second inner loop to increment instead of decrement and I moved the echo outside the second inner loop

```
<?php 
    $a=$_GET["number"];

    for ($i=1;$i<=$a;$i++)
    {
        $result=1;
        for ($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
        {
            $result=$result*$i;
        }

        $result1=1;
        for ($x=1; $x<=$i; $x++)
        {
            $result1 = $result1*$x;
        } 
        echo $result/$result1."</br>";
    }
?>
```